# Why some functions of itertools isn't accessible when import full module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I want to use count function from itertools module.  When I try to import full module

```
import itertools
```

The count function isn't accessible.  I can use it only when I import it like this

```
from itertools import count
```

how I can import full module functions without importing them one by one

Comment: Are you trying to call `count`, or `itertools.count` in the first case? When using `import X` syntax, you always have to qualify names from the module with `X.`. You could avoid namespace qualification with `from itertools import *`, but [that's generally frowned on](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) (namespaces are a good thing for avoiding accidental name collisions, and using `from x import *` prevents static analyzers from doing their job as well).

Comment: I call count without mentioning itertools.  Now I understood what I was doing wrong . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you only need the `count` function it is much more economical to use

```py
from itertools import count
```

If you need the whole module just import it like this:

```py
from itertools import *  # to be avoided due to potential name collusions

print(count(10))
```

or import everything using the module's full name:

```py
import itertools

print(itertools.count(10))
```

or use a shortcut to `itertools`:

```py
import itertools as it

print(it.count(10))
```

Comment: Thanks,  but why when I import module via import itertools it is not importing all functionality?

Comment: If you only type `import itertools` the module is imported using its module name and its funcionality is accessible via `itertools.count()`

Comment: I edited my answer to show all import options.